# Use what to represent apostrophe,Greater,Less Than Sign in Silverlight for SMS

Tags: windows-phone-7

It seems I run out of ideas of what to use to represent in Silveright textBlock for the below to send out by SMS.

For these Characters

Greater and less than sign  ----I use  `&#60` and `&#62;` 
Apostrophe ----- I use `&#39;` or `&apos;`

They look fine in Silverlight TextBlock and TextBox, But When you send them out in SMS, they dont work, they apper in the form of code like `&amp;apos;`  `&amp;#60` or  `&amp;#62;`

1)Say Silverlight textBlock contain Greater and Less Than sign and apostrophe

2) then the textBox1.text = txtBlk.text

```
SmsComposeTask sms = new SmsComposeTask();
 sms.Body = textBox1.Text 
 sms.Show();
```

Any1 can help on this?

----Update-------This is the Code I use :

1) in XAML

<textBlock Name="txtBlkChar" TextWrapping="Wrap">
  &#160;&lt;&#39;&gt;|||-&lt;&#39;&gt;<LineBreak/>
</textBlock>

> refer to &#160; for space

2) In Code Behind :

```
  SmsComposeTask sms = new SmsComposeTask();
   sms.Body = txtBlkChar.Text;
   sms.Show();
```

When you send out the SMS. There chars remain the same such as these:

`&amp;#160;&amp;lt;&amp;#39;&amp;gt;|||-&amp;lt;&amp;#39;&amp;gt;`

3) The same result , If I pass the text in TextBlock to TextBox1.

TxtBox1.text = txtBlkChar.text

Comment: I'v updated the formatting of your code to display ampersands correctly. Can you check that these updates correctly  reflect your code.

Comment: why are you using &#160; for "space"? The ASCII code for a space is 32.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is. If I use the following:

```
var sms = new SmsComposeTask();
sms.Body = "< ' >";
sms.Show();
```

these characters are correctly displayed in the compose dialog and are displayed as above when received by the other phone.

If the problem is the display of the characters on the recipient phone then it may be an encoding issue somewhere in the network(s) you are send through.

In terms of using XAML, the following works for me:

xaml (any of the following work for me):

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myBody">&lt; ' &gt;</TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Name="myBody">&lt; &apos; &gt;</TextBlock>
<TextBlock x:Name="myBody">&#60; &#39; &#62;</TextBlock>
```

cs:

```
sms.Body = myBody.Text;
```

This displays correctly in the compose dialog and in on the recipient phone. I've tested in the emulator and on an actual device. (Although I didn't send from the emulator-obviously.)

I'm using regional/language settings for "United States" (in Emulator) and "United Kingdom" (on device). Can you confirm which regional/language settings you are using.
Can you also confirm if you are not seeing things formatted correctly in the compose dialog of the emulator or phone or on the recipient phone.

Also, why are you encoding characters this way? Even ones you don't need to (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970677.aspx)

Comment: @Matt, Thank for the info. My problem is I am getting the Greater and less than sign and Apostophe sign FROM silverlight TEXTBLOCK.

Comment: @Matt, So I need a way to represent Greater ,Less Than and apostrophe in TextBlock first. Later , I create SMS and get the text from the TextBlock. But use the whatI mentioned not working.

Comment: @MilkBottle I've updated my answer with an example which works for me. What XAML have you tried? (I'm not clear from your question)

Comment: @Matt, I have updated my code. These characters represented by code can not be represented in ASCII in SMS whether sending or receiving.

Comment: @Matt: The Display in Emulator is Correct. Wl Region settings play a play in displaying? I send to my own HD7 n it is not correctly display. My Region used Asian. May be other can. Why I use this? It is for creative communication:)

Comment: @MilkBottle there isn't a region setting called "Asia" what regionsla nad language settings are you using on the sending and recipient devices? If this only happens on the recipient phone have you tested sending the same messages using 2 non-WP7 phones? To determine if the issue is with WP7 or the network encoding of messages as they are sent.